# Can't initialize iScroll

Tags: javascript, iscroll

I'm trying out [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/) and following the documentation, but for some reason I can't get it to initialize. At least, I don't think I can. From the demos and code, I'm not exactly sure what I should expect it to look like!

I've got this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/iScroll/iscroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myScroll;
        function loaded() {
            myScroll = new IScroll('#scroll', {
                mouseWheel: true,
                scrollbars: true
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loaded()">
    <div id="scroll">
        <div>...Lots of Lorem Ipsum text here...</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the sake of tidiness, I've not included the actual text I've got in the `div` I want to scroll, but all I've got is lots and lots of text - enough to make the page need to scroll. The reference to the iScroll file is definitely correct, even with its mixed cases.

I added in the options (*mouseWheel* and *scrollbars*) just to try and make something happen so that I could determine whether the script was being initialized. Setting *scrollbars* to false doesn't seem to make any difference. Bizarrely, if I set *mouseWheel* to false my mousewheel works, but if I set it to true it doesn't - exactly the opposite of the documentation.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I can't see what - it doesn't get more basic than what I'm trying. I looked at the [barebone example](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/barebone/) from the documentation, but that doesn't seem to work for me either, in that there are no scrollbars displayed anywhere. I'm getting the same behaviour in Chrome (48) and IE11.

Comment: "in that there are no scrollbars displayed anywhere" the barebone example doesn't have `scrollbars: true`

Comment: Fair enough, though that seems odd for a demonstration of a scrollbar plugin.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the purpose of iScroll. It was born because mobile browsers didn't update the document while you where scrolling and hence you had no control over it. iScroll is a reimplementation of native scrolling using JavaScript. Scrollbars are just an small feature.

Comment: You're right, I had misunderstood that, thanks for the info. Nevertheless, it seems to be capable of producing customisable scrollbars, which is what I need, but I can't get it to work.